# input `type=image` onclick solution works, but why?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, button

I had a problem using input `type=image` tag with `onclick` to run some javascript. Works perfectly with input `type=button` but, when used on an image input, it would run the script which changed the DOM (added images to a `div`) but would clear back to the default page within fractions of a second, the added images showing as a brief flash then disappearing.

So, using google, I eventually found a solution. I changed:

```
<input type="image" id="greenGoButton" src="Images2/goButton.png" alt="Submit" onclick="loopForm(document.thisForm); getPlates(document.thisForm);">
```

to:

```
<input type="image" id="greenGoButton" src="Images2/goButton.png" alt="Submit" onclick="loopForm(document.thisForm); getPlates(document.thisForm); return false;">
```

So, adding a `return false;` statement fixed it.

But why? This is bugging me. Why does it work without `return false` on a button but not when an image is used instead? Surely the internet is full of buttons made of images.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `type='image'` creates a button that submits the enclosing form and reloads the page, by adding `return false` at the end of the click handler, you are telling Javascript to prevent the default behavior which is submitting the form and reloading the page.

You can also access the event object inside the click handler and call `preventDefault()` on it without doing `return false` at the end; `event.preventDefault()` which also does the same thing.

In short, `return false` at the end of an event handler prevents the default behavior from happening

Comment: As OP observed, `type='button'` doesn't submit, but `type='image'` does: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/coguf1aw/

Comment: @ChrisG Good to know

Comment: Thanks heaps. One more brick in the coding wall.